# What is the name of the genre of games similar to Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to figure out what the genre of games is called in which the only (or primary) control is to hold a single down a button to move the vehicle/character up and when letting go of the button, you float or move down. You generally try to avoid obstacles by moving above or below them.

Examples of this genre would be [The Helicopter Game](http://www.helicoptergame.net/), or Jetpack Joyride. There are no doubt many others that you may have run across over time as well. I just didn't know if there was a genre name for them. I've seen things like 'cave flyer' or 'dodging', didn't know if there was anything better or official to classify them.

Comment: I'm not sure there is one, but this is a super question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are usually called "endless survival games" and are in the same vein as [Canabalt](http://www.adamatomic.com/canabalt/) or [Robot Unicorn Attack](http://games.adultswim.com/robot-unicorn-attack-twitchy-online-game.html).

Answer (score 22):

Another term for games like these are "infinite runners".

Answer (score 5):

I've heard "auto-runner" on some gaming podcasts, because your character constantly/automatically runs. It doesn't seem to be very widespread though--Googling it mainly turns up task scheduling programs.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes they are just called "One Button Games". Kongregate has an entire section devoted to them [here](http://www.kongregate.com/one-button-games?pdis=qj-b&srid=15). I guess it depends how specific you want to limit the genre to.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the developer](http://www.halfbrick.com/our-games/jetpack-joyride/) Jetpack Joyride is in the genre **Joyride 'Em Up**.

I guess if it's their game they get to decide.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but I'm looking for something that encompasses the entire group of games, not just Jetpack Joyride. Only using it as an example because that's the one I played most recently.

Comment: They get to decide on the marketing for their game, but I don't think they get to decide the name of an existing genre.

Comment: [Fruit Ninja](http://www.halfbrick.com/our-games/fruit-ninja/) is "Slash 'em up", and [Monster Dash](http://www.halfbrick.com/our-games/monster-dash/) is "Run and Jump 'em up" -- I'm not sure I'd take them too seriously.